# Installing X11 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, xorg

```
sudo apt-get install x11
Reading package lists ... Done
Dependency tree is being created
Read status information ... Done
E: x11 package not found
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  Yes you are correct, the is no X11 package, but nor should there be!  See https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=x11 if you want to check.  What do you want? as you don't actually have a question

Answer (score 7):

You're probably wanting to install the [**`xorg`**](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/xorg) package, which provides the standard X11 implementation on Ubuntu.

Try: `sudo apt install xorg`